# Pointers used as arrays in function (C)

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

`test(int arr[])` and `test(int *arr)` are equivalent expressions.

So I want to ask what applies to `test(int **ar)`?

update:

I need to call in main the function `test(int *k,int **c)` and I can't understand what values are transferred from the main to test.

For example if I had two arrays `K[3]` and `C[24]` and I wanted to use these two as parameters I would call in main as `test(K,C);` and the function would be declared as `void test(int k[ ],int c[ ]);`

In this example `k[0]=K[0]`,`k[1]=K[1]`,`k[2]=K[2]`,`k[3]=K[3]` and `c[0]=C[0]`..`c[24]=C[24]` etc.

So I want to understand in function `test(int *k,int **c)` what happens with the values of the parameters

Comment: If you're asking whether `test(int **ar)` and `test(int *ar[])` are equivalent, the answer is yes. If you're not, then clarify your question.

Comment: Although the compiler treats them identical, there is of course a semantical difference. With `int arr[]` you tell the programmer it is indeed an array, but with `int *arr` you say no more than that it is a pointer which can point to a single element or possibly an array.

Comment: `k[0]=K[0]`  - of course that is true they are the same thing.  It is not clear what you are trying to say with that explanation.  A pointer to a pointer may be the type of a two dimensional array, or it may be intended that the function modify the pointer pointed to.  The usage is entirely dependent on context.  Semantically it is a pointer to a pointer, nothing more.  It can be used in many different ways - you need a concrete example.

Comment: We'd need to see the implementation or documentation of `test(int *k,int **c)` to determine that.  Insufficient context.

Answer (score 1):

Quote from [N1570](http://chimera.roma1.infn.it/SP/COMMON/iso-iec-9899-1990.pdf) 6.7.6.3 Function declarators (including prototypes):

> 7
> A declaration of a parameter as ‘‘array of type’’ shall be adjusted to ‘‘qualified pointer to
> type’’

`int **ar` is "a pointer to `int*`, so "an array of `int*`" `int *ar[]` will be adjusted to that when it is used as a function argument.

Comment: That, but not only that.  It could also be a pointer or a single pointer or a 2D array  passed as an argument.  If the question is how should `test(int *k,int **c)` be called - we cannot tell.